# UISplitViewController => shouldHideViewController animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to animate my MasterViewController when it appears/disappears. For hidding my master, i use `shouldHideViewController` in my UISplitViewController class.

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return hiddenMaster;
}
```

My question is: is there any method called after `shouldHideViewController` return YES or NO? It seems that `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` are both not called.

Or, more generaly, is there any way to animate my masterView when it appears/disappears?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do something similar to the below UGLY method for disappearing but I wont recommend doing it.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.5 animations:^{
            [self.masterPopoverController.contentViewController.view.superview.superview setCenter:CGPointMake(-300, -300)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        }];
```